# Sql query for deleting a member by email in Umbraco8

Tags: umbraco, umbraco8

Does anyone know of any query to delete a member in Umbraco 8 using sql. I had created a member which is corrupt now and creating errors in backoffice, so i want to delete it

Comment: Have you tried using the member service for deleting that member?
You can write the code in a template and assign it to a test node and call it from the front-end. Example:
var member = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MemberService.GetById(ID); // or use GetByEmail(string email)
ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MemberService.Delete(member);

Answer (score 0):

I assigned the wrong email address to a new user, so I recreated the user with the correct email address and ended up with a disabled user which never is going to be used. I noticed that you can only "disable" users in the Umbraco back office.

I managed to delete the user via some SQL statements.
But because of some foreign keys, it took some extra steps.

1: Look up all users and thus their respective ID

```
 SELECT * FROM [yourDBname].[dbo].[umbracoUser]
```

[selection umbracoUser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUf4a.png)

For example, you want to delete the user with id 4. In your case the corrupted member.

2:  Delete the user with the respective id from the umbracoUserLogin table

```
  DELETE FROM [yourDBname].[dbo].[umbracoUserLogin] WHERE userId = 4
```

3: Do the same thing for the umbracoUser2UserGroup

```
  DELETE FROM [yourDBname].[dbo].[umbracoUser2UserGroup] WHERE userId = 1
```

4: Lastly delete the user from the umbracoUser table

```
    DELETE FROM [yourDBname].[dbo].[umbracoUser] WHERE id = 4
```

Because of the foreign keys, you should delete user rows in this order ([umbracoUserLogin] -> [umbracoUser2UserGroup] -> [umbracoUser]) otherwise, you get an error that you can't delete the row because of the foreign key.

Comment: OP asked how to delete an umbraco member, not an umbraco user.